# Using unicode symbols in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode

Some unicode symbols work when I print a ggplot in my R interface, others work when I print them as a pdf. I'm looking to understand this process. for instance:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(showtext)

d1 <- data.frame(
  yvar = letters[1:3] %>% 
    rep(each = 4),
  xvar = LETTERS[1:4] %>% 
    rep(times = 3),
  ev = sample(1:4, size = 12, replace = T)
   ) %>%
  tbl_df %>% 
  modify(factor)

p1 <- d1 %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(xvar, yvar, shape = ev)
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 8)  +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("\u25BA","\u25D0","\u25BC","\u25B2"))

p1
```

prints

[image: r_session_figure]

while if I print the plot as a pdf, after enabling the use of the Open Sans typeface, I see this

[image]

```
showtext.auto()
ggsave(
  "plot 1.pdf", 
  p1,
  width = 4,
  height = 2
  )
```

How do I enable the greatest number of unicode symbols in `ggplot2`?

(edit: my system info)

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Comment: maybe try using `cairo_pdf`;  ps probably worth adding your system info as this will likely be OS dependent